# lookup module fail to compute value of a template using regex_replace filter

Tags: ansible

This seems to be a bug. But before posting an issue to ansible's github project, I ask here.

Playbook :

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
    - template: >
        dest=/tmp/test.xml
        src=test.xml.j2
    - debug: msg="{{ lookup( 'template', 'test.xml.j2' ) }}"
  vars:
    - command: 'echo "word1 word2"'
```

test.xml.j2

```
<command>ssh {{ command| regex_replace('"(.*)"', '"\\"\1\\""') }} #1</command>
<command>ssh {{ command| regex_replace('"(.*)"', '"\\"\\1\\""') }} #2</command>
```

Test command

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -D -C
```

Expected result : same result on the two tasks

Actual results (ansible 2.3.1.0) :

- when escaping once, template module fail to display first reference
- when escaping twice, lookup module fail to dereference second reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template` action and `template` lookup are known to give different results in several cases.

You may feel free to file an issue.

As a workaround, you can use `set` in your template:

```
{% set repl = '"\\"\\1\\""' %}
<command>ssh {{ command| regex_replace('"(.*)"', '"\\"\1\\""') }} #1</command>
<command>ssh {{ command| regex_replace('"(.*)"', '"\\"\\1\\""') }} #2</command>
<command>ssh {{ command| regex_replace('"(.*)"', repl) }} #3</command>
```

Here `#3` gives the same result both with action and with lookup:

```
- template:
    dest: /tmp/test.xml
    src: test.xml.j2
- copy:
    content: "{{ lookup( 'template', 'test.xml.j2' ) }}"
    dest: /tmp/test2.xml
```

result:

```
<command>ssh echo "\"\"" #1</command>
<command>ssh echo "\"word1 word2\"" #2</command>
<command>ssh echo "\"word1 word2\"" #3</command>

<command>ssh echo "\"word1 word2\"" #1</command>
<command>ssh echo "\"\1\"" #2</command>
<command>ssh echo "\"word1 word2\"" #3</command>
```